# Good book references for physics and math for electronics

Tags: embedded, math, physics, books

Next year I'll join an engineer school in Dijon, France in the field of **Electronics (Embedded Systems)**. I am currently taking a 2 years general IT education and my main problem is that I am very bad in math and I have no real basis in physics. So I'm wondering if you can help me with some book titles to get me started. I used to be good in math but I made the mistake to take one year of law (I know...) so I forgot everything. I really need a book that explains concepts very thoroughly and that features exercises & their correction. If you can think of books other than math and physics that could help me, feel free to propose. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend "The Art of Electronics" to you.  Very gentle on the math and very thorough.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Electronics

Math is your friend in electronics but maybe you'll begin to enjoy it.  That is the difference between being good and not

Comment: It's not that I don't like math, I would love to be good in it. But I need to start slowly and make sure I fully understand each concept I come across. Since I have lost connection with the subject during a year, I feel my current classes are going too fast. But thank you for your recommendation.

Comment: Look at: Stroud, 'Engineering Mathematics'